# Booting from a compressed iso file

Tags: boot, formatting, iso-image, compression

I'm trying to format my PC from USB, since booting from CD won't work. I'm trying to make a USB bootable .ISO file from a win7 CD. Now I've created a .iso file whose size turned out to be 4.29 GB. My USB stick is only 4GB Searching through the site, some of you suggested to compress it. Now, can I boot the PC in he regular way from a compressed image?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be there as a possible task assuming you can have it written but then again you are looking at some really tightly compressed and encrypted BS so why is there a problem with getting a 64GB or so stick to boot from?
 Get Hirans boot cd too...
Also be aware that the bootstick procedure sometimes does not do the job fully that does not mean your stick won't
  boot just that you have to run a hiran's utility (from mini-XP)
 or some other bootstick maker.. it may not have been necessary
 on a stick but you find a new stick seems to be unbootable 
because the copyrighted IBM-CP/m bootstrap is not fully in place for the USB device,
 In addition to Hiran consider looking for AIO for AIO images of Windows.